# Does anyone have the formula for the damage multipliers in Tiny Dice Dungeon?

Tags: android, tiny-dice-dungeon

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet that allows me to enter the stats for the four collectibles I equip to my character.

I want to know based on the four collectibles I chose what my damage will be against the varying types of monsters.  I can't seem to get the math right.

I find the section of Advancing Levels somewhat confusing in how it's written

http://www.tinydicedungeon.com/Guide/GuideIndex.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from [TINY DICE DUNGEON [WIKI]](http://tinydicedungeon.wikia.com/wiki/Items):

For "regular" damage (Physical and Elemental based):

> A fire monster equipped with a '+5% fire attack' item will: A) Do 5% more damage against fire, and B) Do 5% more damage with fire-based attacks.
>
> Items will NOT boost each other's bonuses, so a +40% attack and a +50% attack will result in 190% total damage, not 210%.
>
> ...
>
> For example:  A +40% Physical ATK item will: A) Add 40% to all Physical damage they do, and B) Add another 20% to all damage against Physical based monsters on top of that for a total of +60% to the damage multiplier (  DamageMultiplierIcon ).

For Poison it is not the multiplier, but the roll, that is affected:

> For example: Rolling a 4 on a poison die with 200% Poison ATK means your "DICE TOTALS: POISON:" will be equal to 12 instead of 4. At least two things are true when it comes to poison attacks: A) The damage multiplier can NEVER effect poison damage, and B) The dice total for poison will always round up (e.g. rolling a 2 on a poison die with an item that boost Poison ATK by +1% will result in a 3).